# DEM, points values and elevation to create a map of temeperature

Tags: elevation, saga, kriging

I am using SAGA - Universal Kriging (Global) for this, but I am stucked. I have grid (.tif) for Serbia with elevation values, and .shp file with points that have mean yearly temperature. I want to create a map using these two files and to take in to the account that Temperature gradient in Serbia is 0.6°C. Temperature gradient means that for every 100m temperature is changed for 0.6°C Also i have the elevation for the .shp file with points, but i don't know how to combine all this.
So I want to display a map of the temperature, extrapolated around the known points according to the DEM.
Is that possible?

Comment: Given you are trying to create a trend surface which later used as an External Drift in UK, may i suggest following steps: (1) multiply temp gradient (-0.6/100m) with elevation grid, then (2) calibrate the map from (1) with your points by `Multiple Regression Analysis` tool (in `Spatial and Geostatistics | Regression`). I think `Regression` output grid is what you need for UK process. (I have not been successful with my laptop as this is intense computing).

Comment: http://fennerschool.anu.edu.au/research/products/anusplin-vrsn-44

Comment: I don't know to the first step. I need more detailed answer please.

Comment: Yep,sorry... For the Step (1), please use `Grid Calculator` (in Tools | Grid | Calculus). With your elevation as Grids (g1), input formula will look like `20 - 0.006 * g1` (20-degC as just an indicative temp at elev=0). Calculated temperature itself is less important (we only need trend) but it helps us to visually compare it with the point data. (Please note it is probably better to smooth your elevation grid beforehand).

Comment: @Kazuhito Thank you very very much!!! I managed to do the following steps. I understand the procedure. But only one more q. Why in this equation you put number 20. - > 20 - 0.006 * g1 (20-degC as just an indicative temp at elev=0)
Can you explain me it with more details?

Comment: @Markoneo  20 degC was just an idea without much thinking... any number will do. Maybe you have a relevant temperature recorded at around sea level in your region, or extrapolate it by fitting your temperature gradient.

Comment: @Kazuhito i don't have temperature recorded at around sea level, but i have temp. gradient it is  0.6°C per 100m elevation. And and i have shp file with points that have mean yearly temp and elevation. You have included that temp. gradient in to the equation. I am confused now. XD

Comment: @Markoneo I do not want to confuse you further, but the point of step 1 is just to obtain trend map and temperature itself is not the focus. It is still nice to have your "pseudo-" temperature map to check it visually against your recorded temperature.

Comment: @Kazuhito Ok. I have compare it with the map i gained with kriging, and results are the same, but more detailed with the use of steps you explained.

Arigato :)

Comment: @Markoneo Great :)

Comment: @Kazuhito I have one more question, sorry. Problem with this Multiple Regression Analysis tool is that the value of the pixel (DEM) where is located my point, is not the same as my point value. For example point value is 9.3, and pixel value after applying Multiple Regression Analysis tool is 9.6. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @Markoneo How about (1) create residual grid, and (2) subtract (or add) this residual?  In detail; Step (1) Calculate the difference (9.6 - 9.3) at the point and store it to the attribute table. Then interpolate (e.g. `Grid - Spline Interpolation | Multilevel B-Spline`) to generate the grid. Step (2) Subtraction - it can be done either by `Grid Calculator` or by `Grid difference` (both in `Grid - Calculus`). But...because the regression grid was meant to be trend surface, it looks within reasonable range (to me). Do you really have to match them?

Comment: @Kazuhito We are doing hydrology and erosion calculation, so every change in the range from 0.1 to 0.5 can have big differences. :)

I'll try to do proposed steps.

Comment: Aah, got that with thanks @Markoneo. I now see it is important. Good luck with your research!

Comment: @Kazuhito  WOOHOO, I have managed to reduce difference to 0.001, which is great!!! :D Thank you so much.
Grid calculator works best, with equation g1 + g2.

Comment: @Markoneo That's truly fabulous. Wow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to summarize the workflow you have taken to obtain a trend surface to be an input grid to the UK algorithm.

Background of this topic would have been like this: (A) There is DEM and measured temperature data available. It is given the temperature generally follow the `-0.6 deg-C per 100m` trend. (B) In perfect world the temperature curve should be like the gray curve, but the recorded temperature show certain deviation.

[image]

So a workflow (detailed below) taken was, create a surface first by **Multiple Regression Analysis** considering both measured temperature and elevation, and then removing residual errors.

1. Create a "pseudo- temperature grid" by multiplying temperature gradient with DEM. [Grid calculator] Recommended equation was `20 - 0.006 * g1` where 20 was notional (intercept) temperature. (It would have been trial and error to find best intercept value).
2. Create a Regression grid from measured temperature data and pseudo-temperature grid. [Multiple Regression Analysis Tool]
3. Create a residual grid by (a) Calculate difference between measured temperature and the regression grid. [Subtract] and store the difference into the attribute table of the measured point shapefile. (b) Interpolate the difference. Recommended tool was [Multilevel B-Spline] but any gridding tool does this job. (c) Subtract this residual grid from the regression grid. [Grid calculator]

Final output is a temperature trend surface (red dots; above picture), conditioned at the measured locations.

---

Markoneo, please edit as you think necessary. I likely have missed some steps you have taken.